# HackerRank "Lily's Homework" - why is number of swaps equal to N - cycles?

Tags: algorithm

I am looking at the HackerRank problem [Lily's Homework](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/lilys-homework/problem):

> Consider an array of  distinct integers, `arr = [a[0],a[1],...,a[n-1]]`. [You] can swap any two elements of the array any number of times. An array is beautiful if the sum of `|arr[i]-arr[i-1]|` among `0<i<n` is minimal.
>
> Given the array `arr`, determine and return the minimum number of swaps that should be performed in order to make the array beautiful.

Can someone explain why in the editorial they state that the number of swaps is N - cycles? I can't understand it when I see the solution, and I feel so uncomfortable if I use the code when I don't know what it is doing.

Answer (score 1):

The solution consists of sorting the array, while remembering for each value its index in the original input array. There are two candidates that minimize the sum of differences: either sorting the input in ascending order, or in descending order. The idea is to count the number of swaps needed for each of the two candidate sort orders and then to return the least of the two.

### Example

Example input with associated indexes. These indexes will "stick" with their values when we will sort the array. Here I will only consider sorting the array in ascending order:

```
[50, 10, 30, 20, 90, 60]
  0   1   2   3   4   5
```

Once sorted, that array looks like this -- the indices remain paired with their value:

```
[10, 20, 30, 50, 60, 90]
  1   3   2   0   5   4
```

Now we can look to the inverse operation: what rotations are needed to return the sorted array back to its original state? We can identify the following cycles:

```
 10 20 __ 50 __ __ -> right rotation -> 50 10 __ 20 __ __

 __ __ 30 __ __ __ -> nothing to do  -> __ __ 30 __ __ __       

 __ __ __ __ 60 90 -> rotation       -> __ __ __ __ 90 60
```

The core of the answer to your question is this: when a cycle consists of  elements, you need  − 1 swaps to perform a rotation. Above we have cycles of sizes 1, 2, and 3. They respectively require 0, 1 and 2 swaps to perform the cycle's rotation.

### The example explored in more detail

In more detail, an algorithm could approach the sorted array like this:

We start at index 0, with value 10: it has to move to index 1, so we swap it with the value at index 1 (20), and we get:

```
[20, 10, 30, 50, 60, 90]
  3   1   2   0   5   4
```

Then we take the swapped value 20, which has to move to index 3, so we swap it with 50:

```
[50, 10, 30, 20, 60, 90]
  0   1   2   3   5   4
```

Then we take 50, which ... does not have to move! We completed a cycle, and achieved with 2 swaps a rotation of 3 values, which all three are now at their correct (original) position.

The algorithm would then look for an index that was not yet visited: index 2.

Here we are lucky, as the value 30 is at its original index: this is a cycle of 1 value, and so 0 swaps are needed.

The algorithm would then look for the next index that was not yet visited: index 4.

The value at index 4 (60) needs to move to index 5, so we swap with value 90.
Then we look again at index 4 where we find that value 90 is at its correct index. And so we rotated a cycle of 2 values with one swap.

Now all is done.

#### Conclusion

The array can be seen of a collection of  cycles, where each value is part of exactly one such cycle. Therefore the sum of the sizes (number of members) of the  cycles will be .

A cycle with  values will need  − 1 swaps to perform the rotation. So all cycles can be rotated by performing  −  swaps.

This also means the algorithm actually doesn't have to *perform* the swaps. It suffices to just identify and count the cycles.

As stated at the top, don't forget you need to check this for the **two** candidate orders to achieve the minimum sum.